# RIA Services OData "Query options are not allowed."

Tags: wcf, wcf-ria-services, odata

I have a OData endpoint which was created automatically by RIA which seems to work with simple 'get' queries.

E.g.

http://xxx/Service/BusinessApplication1-Web-DomainService1.svc/odata/ProductSet

But when I try to use queries such as 'where' or 'top', e.g:

.../BusinessApplication1-Web-DomainService1.svc/odata/ProductSet?$top=50

results in 'Query options are not allowed.'

I set up a WCF Data Service that has a OData endpoint which works fine and allows queries, so why does the RIA generated one not work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The OData endpoint exposed by a RIA service doesn't currently support query operators. There's no real workaround for that either (as far as I know).

Answer (score 0):

And other [limitations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2010/11/19/how-to-open-a-wcf-ria-services-application-to-other-type-of-clients-the-odata-endpoint-2-5.aspx).