# Adding HTML5 to WCF/Ria Services

Tags: html, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I have an existing WCF/RIA Services app.  The front-end is all Silverlight.  We would like to add some HTML5 pages to the app to support tablets.  It would be nice if the HTML pages could call the DomainService methods.

Any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to expose a JSON end point from WCF RIA than you can consume that in HTML5 just by writing some javascript code.

this might help: http://www.neelesh-vishwakarma.com/2013/05/windows-8-parsing-json-twitter-api.html

Comment: It seems right, previously I tried it by ODATA&JSON endpoint. When you use ria services odata endpoint you will see that some functions are restricted(not supported).Query operations are not supported http://stackoverflow.com/q/3522544/413032 ,so you can't use default domain service methods always,anyway,,, I preferred another way, coding an abstract rest service ,the rest service uses my old domain services when needed.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm new to web apps.  How do I "code an abstract rest service"? I know how to code it, I just need help adding it to my existing solution.